# Is there any way to summarize text data which has numbers and tables in python, either extractive way or abstarctive way?

Tags: machine-learning, text, deep-learning, nlp, summarization

I am dealing with tons of PDF documents (petetions data) filled with text data having numbers, tabular data etc. The objective of client is to summarize any such given document to reduce man-force in reading the entire document. I have tried conventional methods like lSA,Gensim-summarizer, BERT extractive summarizer, Pysummarizer.

The results are not at all good, Please suggest me any way where i can find a industry level summarizer(extrative/abstractive) that would give me a good start to solve this issue .

Answer (score 2):

First, you will need to know exactly what data the company wants abstracted from the documents.  After that, you may be able to convert the documents to raw text using OCR or some other PDF application, and then extract the data you need.  If the company isn't being clear on how they want you to summarize the data, that would be something to talk to them about.  It might be as simple as setting a title for the document, or classifying it.  If it's document classification I can help you with that, I made a repo for that purpose a little while ago.

Comment: Yes, the company is unsure of what they want. The legal documents have lot of content and extensive manual work is required to summarize such document for further decision making. Hence, client wants us to create a pipeline for summarization. The raw data has ample of scanned images,tables etc. which makes it harder for conventional techniques.  Although, i have applied all techniques after OCR the results are not good.